# Get nav menu item custom field value

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom walker for my navigation menu, inside which I want to get the menu item custom field value to further customize my menu items. Here is my code..

My menu item custom field is `menu-item-mymenucolor`

and I want to get its value in `$menu_color` (currently I get blank!)

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'   => 'primary',
    'walker' => new WPDocs_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    )
);

// Custom Nav Menu walker class.
class WPDocs_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

    // Depth-dependent classes.
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0

    // Custom nav menu item custom field value i want to get in the $classes.
    $menu_color = '"style="background-color: '.get_post_meta($item->ID, 'menu-item-mymenucolor', true).';';

    // Combine values of classes.
    $classes = array(
        'dropdown-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth,
        ''. $menu_color
    );

    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // Build HTML for output.
    $output .=  ($depth == 0) ? "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n" . "\n <div class=\"megamenu-content\">\n"  . "\n<div class=\"row\">\n" : "\n<ul class=\"elementy-ul\">\n";
    }

// Start the element output codes from here.....

}
```

Actually I can easily get the value of Woocommerce in the `$menu_color` place by just inserting the $woocommerce global variable, so is there anything to do with global variables? here take a look at this,

```
 global $woocommerce;

    // get cart quantity
    $cart_qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $classes = array(
        'dropdown-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth,
        ''. $cart_qty
    );
```

Whereas, its much easier to get the menu item custom field value inside start element of this walker section, I will just post an important part of the code to make it short. I hope you understand where it must have been..

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' style="background-color: '.get_post_meta($item->ID, 'menu-item-mymenucolor', true).';">';
$item_output .= '</a>';
```

I have tried almost every possibilities to get the value but none could work as of now. I know this will absolutely work like a charm, but I think i am missing something important here.

So, Is there any way this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$item->object_id` instead of `$item->ID` and everything will work fine.

Maybe this is a late answer but since no one answered till now I thought it's a good idea to answer it, maybe it will help someone else too.